# java vm options having + and - symbols

Tags: java

what does "+" and "-" sign refer in vm options

```
java -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:-UseParallelOldGC TestGC
java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:-UseParNewGC  TestGC
```

we can see the **"+UseParallelGC"** and **"-UseParallelOldGC"** having + and - sign, what these signify

Comment: It's to turn this on (+) or off (-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly from the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html):

```
Boolean options are turned on with -XX:+<option> and turned off with -XX:-<option>
```

Please note `+` for option ON and `-` for option off